# How are props being passed down in this case?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

My question is how the props are being passed down to the component `NotificationScreen` below.

This component has a class definition in React Native that goes somewhat like this :

```
class NotificationScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
    this.state = {...};
  }

          .
          .
          .
}

const mapStateToProps = (store) => ({
  user: store.userState.user,
  theme: store.userState.theme,
  notifications: store.notificationState.notifications,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(NotificationScreen);
```

and the only place where it is used is here:

```
import NotificationScreen from '_scenes/Notification/notification';

const router = {
  Notification: {
    screen: NotificationScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      headerTitle: 'Notification',
    },
  }
}


const config = {
  initialRouteName: 'Notification',
  header: null,
  headerMode: 'none',
};

const NotificationStack = createStackNavigator(router, config);

export default NotificationStack;
```

I just can't understand how the props are being passed down to `NotificationScreen`. Shouldn't it be something like this :

```
<NotificationScreen wasRead = {true} createdAt = {'12/12/2021'} />
```

Comment: I'm guessing the call to [`connect`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect) is what's doing it; maybe read that documentation.

Comment: Please refer this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/redux-integration/